# For Loop Breaks after wrapping with Platypus

Tags: bash, shell, backup, platypus

Below is a snippet of a script I am working on for media backup. The script runs as expected when called from the Terminal command line. However, after wrapping the script with Platypus in to an App, the destination directory is created but the For Loop does not run and no media is copied to the destination folder. Anyone know what I am doing wrong here??

```
#!/bin/sh

DEST_PATH=/Volumes/MediaBackup   
mkdir -p $DEST_PATH    
SAVEIFS=$IFS

IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

for i in $(find "$PWD" -iname "*.jpg")    
do      
    FILENAME="$(basename $i)"
    MD5="$(md5 -q $i)"
    cp "$i" "$DEST_PATH/$MD5-$FILENAME"
done 

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Gentle dudes and/or ladies, THANKYOU! Below is the working script using your comments. Thanks for a quick turn around. Should've done this days ago.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEST_PATH=/Volumes/PrivateMain/Media
mkdir -p $DEST_PATH
SAVEIFS=$IFS

IFS=$(printf "\n\b")

for i in $(find "/Users" -iname "*.jpg") 
do
FILENAME="$(basename $i)"
MD5="$(md5 -q $i)"

cp "$i" "$DEST_PATH/$MD5-$FILENAME"

done 

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: Is it possible that Platypus is changing your current working directory?  You explicitly name the output directory, so there is no ambiguity as to where that will go, but were the `$PWD` to change, you may be somewhere where the `find` comes up empty.

Comment: Probably  unrelated, but see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over the output of `find`.

Comment: It sounds like you are running your script with `bash` from the command line, but it is being run with `/bin/sh` in the Platypus-wrapped version. `echo` will behave differently in each case. (Namely, `-e` is treated by `/bin/sh` as a literal string to output, not an option to enable processing of escaped characters.) Use `printf '\n\b'` instead for portable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

DEST_PATH=/Volumes/PrivateMain/Media
mkdir -p $DEST_PATH
SAVEIFS=$IFS

IFS=$(printf "\n\b")

for i in $(find "/Users" -iname "*.jpg") 
do
FILENAME="$(basename $i)"
MD5="$(md5 -q $i)"

cp "$i" "$DEST_PATH/$MD5-$FILENAME"

done 

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Thanks to all who helped out! However, due to the possibility of overwriting 2 of the same named files, I have edited the script to as below.

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(printf "\n\b")
COUNTER=0;
for i in $(find "/Users" -iname "*.jpg");
do

BASE=`expr "$i" : '.*/\(.*\)\..*'`;
EXT=`expr "$i" : '.*/.*\.\(.*\)'`;
COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1` ;
cp "$i" ""${tardir}"/"$x"/JPG/"$BASE"_"$COUNTER"."$EXT""

done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: I think you want `cp "$i" "${tardir}/$x/JPG/${BASE}_$COUNTER.$EXT"`.